# Scanning from .NET scanner's GUI opens and then closes

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, image-scanner, twain

I developed a winform .NET 4 application that has the ability to asyncronous save image from scanner using Bytescout Scan.
Anyway I noticed that in some cases (with some scanners) the scanner's GUI opens and then closes immediately after load without performing any scan.
Since no error message is raised either from my code and from scanner software itself; is there some settings/tweak somewhere I should pay attention?
Thanks for your suggestions, Giuseppe

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a scanning library from Bytescout you'll need to contact them. Send them the names of the scanners where you see this issue. Their scanning software may not be compatible with the twain drivers for those scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Every TWAIN-compliant Source provides a user interface specific to its particular device. When
the application user selects the Acquire option, the Source’s User Interface may be displayed.
If desired, the application can write its own version of this interface, too.

Of course, you can choose to disable that interface. Please refer to TWAIN_2_1_Spec.pdf (Page 18) for more information.

Other TWAIN SDKs provide easier way to manage this. For example, you can just set IfShowUI to false in Dynamic .NET TWAIN to disable the scanner Interface